# Listing Duplicate Words

Tags: 14.04, bash

I have a file which looks like:

```
(aa,((bb,cc),dd));
(((aa,cc),ee),(ff,gg));
((aa,ff),hh);
```

Each line actually represents a phylogenetic tree in [newick](http://marvin.cs.uidaho.edu/Teaching/CS515/newickFormat.html) format. I would like to list all the names that have duplicates, i.e. occurrence>1. For example, in this case the output is:

```
aa, cc, ff
```

Comment: Is it essential that the output be a comma-separated list? Would something as simple as `grep -Po '\w+' file | sort | uniq -d` suffice?

Comment: @steeldriver add a `tr '\n' ','` to it? :D

Comment: @muru I prefer glenn jackman's `paste -sd,` (doesn't leave a nasty trailing comma)

Comment: @steeldriver both answers work, thanks, you guys rock!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '\n' < file | sort | uniq -d | paste -sd,
```

That `tr` command converts all sequences of non-letters into a newline

Comment: @steeldriver, I promise you I devised this answer without seeing your comment

Comment: n/p, I upvoted - `tr` is probably more efficient than anything regex based anyway